# Trying to get a PowerShell script to run a nuget.exe command

Tags: powershell, nuget

I'm trying to run the following command in a PowerShell script.

`nuget pack MyNuGetSpec.nuspec -Version 1.2.3-alpha`

When I have this PS code, I get an error..

Code:

```
"NuGet packing $file to a .nupkg ..."
$exe = $path + "nuget.exe pack $file -Version $version"

$exe

&$exe
```

and the error message..

> NuGet packing MyNuGetSpec.nuspec to a .nupkg ... C:\Projects\Foo\NuGet
>   Package Specifications\nuget.exe pack MyNuGetSpec.nuspec -Version
>   1.2.3-alpha & : The term 'C:\Projects\Foo\NuGet Package Specifications\nuget.exe pack MyNuGetSpec.nuspec -Version 1.2.3-alpha'
>   is not recognized  as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
>   operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
>   included, verify that the path is correct and  try again. At
>   C:\Projects\Foo\NuGet Package Specifications\build.ps1:106 char:10
>   +         &$exe
>   +          ~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Projects\Foo... 0.1.0-alpha:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

```
$path == Directory: C:\Projects\Foo\NuGet Package Specifications
$file == `MyNuGetSpec.nuspec`
$version == 0.1.0-alpha`
```

Lastly, I have the .exe side-by-side (in the same folder) as the `.nuspec` file.

Answer (score 8):

You need to separate the executable name from the arguments:

```
$exe = $path + "nuget.exe"

&$exe pack $file -Version $version
```

Answer (score 6):

Minor alteration,

```
 $path="c:\..."
 $file= "MyNuGetSpec.nuspec"
 $version= "0.1.0-alpha"
 Invoke-Expression "$($path)\nuget.exe pack $($file) -Version $($version)"
```

This should execute nuget.exe with appropriate parameters

Comment: How does this differ to @mickyBalladelli's answer?

Comment: When using `&`, the arguments are passed as-is separately. When using `Invoke-Expression` in this case, it will generate the full string first, then evaluate that string as powershell code. The `&` command is much safer since it will only expand the `$exe`. When using `Invoke-Expression` if `$file` has a semicolon and second command, you've got a problem.